# React Native - large header in android platform

Tags: react-native, stack, react-navigation

I have an issue in the header in the stack, when the app first time render, for a milliseconds the welcome title will be in the top and than it will add the height. any help?
[image of the header is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un7uK.png)

```js
import { registerIndieID } from "native-notify";
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";
import WelcomePage from "./screens/Welcome";
import ProductCard from "./components/productCard";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Nav from "./components/nav";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";
import AddressBook from "./components/AddressBook";
import AddressBookEdit from "./components/AddressBook_edit";
import ChangePassword from "./screens/ChangePassword";
import MyCoupon from "./screens/myCoupon";
import PurchasedDeals from "./screens/purchasedDeals";
import UsedDeals from "./screens/usedDeals";
import ReservedDeals from "./screens/reservedDeals";
import Contact from "./screens/contactus";
import MyDetails from "./screens/MyDetails";
import About from "./screens/aboutUs";
import AboutCoupway from "./screens/aboutCoupWay";
import TermsCondition from "./screens/termsCondition";
import AppSetting from "./screens/appSetting";
import Checkout from "./screens/Checkout";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import FiltratedOffers from "./screens/customFiltrationScreen.js";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const screenOptions = {
  headerTintColor: "white",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#13d0ca",
  },
  navigationOptions: {
    headerForceInset: { vertical: "never" },
  },
  tabBarStyle: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    elevation: 0,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "#13d0ca",
  },
};

export const BasketContext = createContext();
export const QueryContext = createContext();
export const LoggedInContext = createContext();
export const UserContext = createContext();

export default function Page() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [basket, setBasket] = useState([]);
  const [queryset, setQueryset] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  // registerNNPushToken(12331, 'L4XCS1Ezhz6YHOS7hIr6hR');
  registerIndieID(user?.user_id, 12331, "L4XCS1Ezhz6YHOS7hIr6hR");

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let data;
      try {
        data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user_data");
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        setUser(parsedData);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]}>
      <LoggedInContext.Provider value={[isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn]}>
        <QueryContext.Provider value={[queryset, setQueryset]}>
          <BasketContext.Provider value={[basket, setBasket]}>
            <Stack.Navigator
              initialRouteName={"Nav"}
              screenOptions={screenOptions}
            >
              {user === null ? (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Welcome">
                    {() => (
                      <WelcomePage
                        setUser={setUser}
                        setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Stack.Screen>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Register">
                    {() => (
                      <Register
                        setUser={setUser}
                        setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Stack.Screen>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Login">
                    {() => (
                      <Login setUser={setUser} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
                    )}
                  </Stack.Screen>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <Stack.Screen name="ProductCard" component={ProductCard} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="Checkout" component={Checkout} />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "MY DETAILS",
                    }}
                    name="MyDetails"
                    component={MyDetails}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen name="AddressBook" component={AddressBook} />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="FiltratedOffers"
                    component={FiltratedOffers}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="ProductScreen"
                    component={ProductScreen}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="ChangePassword"
                    component={ChangePassword}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "edit address",
                    }}
                    name="AddressBookEdit"
                    component={AddressBookEdit}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "MY COUPON",
                    }}
                    name="MyCoupon"
                    component={MyCoupon}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "ABOUT COUPWAY",
                    }}
                    name="AboutCoupway"
                    component={AboutCoupway}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "TERMS & CONDITION",
                    }}
                    name="TermsCondition"
                    component={TermsCondition}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "PURCHASED DEALS",
                    }}
                    name="PurchasedDeals"
                    component={PurchasedDeals}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "APP SETTING",
                    }}
                    name="AppSetting"
                    component={AppSetting}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "ABOUT US",
                    }}
                    name="AboutUs"
                    component={About}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "USED DEALS",
                    }}
                    name="UsedDeals"
                    component={UsedDeals}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    options={{
                      title: "RESERVED DEALS",
                    }}
                    name="ReservedDeals"
                    component={ReservedDeals}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="ContactUs"
                    component={Contact}
                    options={{
                      title: "CONTACT US",
                    }}
                  />
                  <Stack.Screen
                    name="Nav"
                    options={{ headerShown: true, header: () => null }}
                  >
                    {() => <Nav user={user} setUser={setUser} />}
                  </Stack.Screen>
                </>
              )}
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </BasketContext.Provider>
        </QueryContext.Provider>
      </LoggedInContext.Provider>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I tried all solutions to solve it but nothing is working,I tried to comment all screens and just let the welcome screen appear and nothing happen, PLEASE HELP! And thanks in advance.